# alternate to storeEval command in Selenium IDE 3.2.3 Chrome Plugin

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Earlier I was using Selenium IDE 2.9.1 plugin in firefox but due to some reason I had to shift to Chrome having Selenium IDE 3.2.3 Plugin.

In the old version I was having below commands to find execution time of a test case:

storeEval | new Date().getTime(); | startTime

-- Some test case data --

storeEval | new Date().gettime(); | endTime

storeEval | (${endTime} - ${startTime}) / 1000 | scriptExecutionTime

echo      | ${scriptExecutionTime} seconds     |

But now in New version in chrome, I could not find the storeEval command.
Can anyone please help me in writing same commands for the new Chrome plugin ?

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never... :D

You can use this :-

```
Command        | Target                                     |   Value
execute script | return new Date().getTime()                |   startTime
execute script | return new Date().getTime()                |   endTime
execute script | return (${endTime} - ${startTime}) / 1000  |   scriptExecutionTime
```